# how can i get multiple value checkbox using modal

Tags: php, html, checkbox, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

How can i show my modal when i click submit?

The output is success without modal but if i use modal popup its show nothing.

This is my body html

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset-4 col-sm-8 mt-5">
                <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="Sepak Bola"> Sepak Bola <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="Membaca"> Membaca <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="Menulis"> Menulis <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="Memancing"> Memancing <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset-5 col-sm-7">
                <input type="submit" name="proses" class="btn btn-primary" value="Proses" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

this is my modal show :

```
 <!-- AWAL MODAL -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="offset-4 col-sm-8 mt-5">
                            <h3>OUTPUT : </h3>
                            <?php
                            if (isset($_POST['proses'])) :
                                if (!empty($_POST['hobby'])) :
                                    foreach ($_POST['hobby'] as $selected) :
                                        echo $selected . "</br>";
                                    endforeach;
                                endif;
                            endif;
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- AKHIR MODAL -->
```

my modal just don't submit the information

Comment: Using 'submit' button, actually submits the form and due to this modal wont show up.  use `button` and try.

Comment: can u show me the code because im newbie

Comment: I dont have code matching your requirement, let me see if i can find some examples.

Comment: you whant the values to be showed on the modal is that?if it's that i can help you on code exemple

Comment: Yes thats wht i mean. Values showed on the modal but hooowwww??? :(

Comment: https://codepen.io/hanapiers/pen/EXNrGP,  might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, as you whant, here is the modal showing the values:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"> 
        <p id="checkid"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<form>
  <h3>Please select:</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-4 col-sm-8 mt-5">
            <input type="checkbox" name="values" value="Sepak Bola"> Sepak Bola <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="values" value="Membaca"> Membaca <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="values" value="Menulis"> Menulis <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="values" value="Memancing"> Memancing <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<button  id = "button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" >modal</button>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function() {
        var p=$("#myModal1 #checkid");
        $(p).html("you have selected:");
        $.each($("input[name='values']:checked"), function() {
            $(p).html($(p).html() + '<br>' + $(this).val());
        });      
    }); 
});
</script>
```